# Append data if value is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append html data if the checkbox value is true

```
if ($('#telephonyeq1').is(":checked") != 'false') {
    $("telephony1 telephony2").html(
        'Telephony: <span style="color: #37b400">' + $('#telephonyeq1').is(":checked") +
        '</span> Service Issues <span style="color: #37b400">' + telephony.value() +
        '</span> - Affected Users: <span style="color: #37b400">' + telephonyaffected.value() +
        '</span>'
    );
}
```

it appends the data always, even if the value is true or false, any advice/help please?

Comment: `if($('#telephonyeq1').is(":checked") != false)` or simple `if($('#telephonyeq1').is(":checked"))` the method returns boolean

Comment: Thanks ! Works perfect !

Comment: @tphil  `$("telephony1 telephony2")`  here you are missing `#` or `.` as it need to be selector

Answer (score 2):

You can do directly:

```
if ($('#telephonyeq1').is(":checked")) {
  ...
}
```

Since `true != "true"` and `true !== "true"` and `false != "false"` and `false !== "false"`, your current code doesn't work as you expect (because you are comparing a boolean with a string).